# Turn on redirected access mode for Server 2012R2 Cluster Shared Volume

Tags: hyper-v, windows-cluster

Server 2008R2 had an option in the Failover Cluster Manager GUI to turn on redirected access mode.  This option seems to be gone in Server 2012R2.

Is there still a way (likely a powershell command) to enable redirected access for a cluster shared volume?  Googling shows plenty of tips on troubleshooting redirected access, but I can't find any to cause it.

Why on earth would I want to do this?  To test that my monitoring system is detecting redirected access properly and alerting me of it.

I could test it by pulling the cables from one of the nodes, but that would affect all the CSVs, not just the one I have set aside for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows Server 2012R2 Failover Cluster Manager, expand `Storage`, select `Disks`, highlight/select your cluster disk in the upper pane, then highlight/select the CSV volume in the lower pane, right click the CSV volume and select `Turn On Redirected Access".

[image]

Comment: Silly me, I had the lower panel hidden...